# Функция некорректно работает со строками в датафрейме pandas

Tags: python-3.x, функции, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так делаю? У меня есть список типа list с номерами продуктов по которым проходит акция (list_promo). Есть фрейм (df), который содержит серию (Код товара) со всеми номерами продуктов. Хочу написать функцию, которая в новой серии проставит соответствующее значение, если номер продукта участвует в акции. Казалось бы простая задача, но у меня почему-то не работает оператор in в моем коде. Не проверяет на вхождение. Код функции очень простой:

```
def Promo(df):
for rec in df['Код товара']:
    if rec in list_promo:
        return True
    return False
```

Далее:

```
df['Акция'] = df.apply(Promo, axis=1)
```

В результате получаю только False. Во фрейме Код товара имеет тип int. лямбда-функцию намеренно не использую, так как функция будет усложняться и скорее всего содержать много строк и условий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Старайтесь избегать циклов при работе с Pandas:

```
df['Акция'] = df['Код товара'].isin(list_promo)
```

или

```
def Promo(df):
    mask = df['Код товара'].isin(list_promo)
    #mask &= another condition
    return mask

df['new'] = Promo(df)
```

Пример:

```
In [17]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   Код товара
0           1
1           2
2           3
3           4
4           5
5           6
6           7
7           1
8           3

In [19]: list_promo = [1,3]

In [20]: df['Акция'] = df['Код товара'].isin(list_promo)

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   Код товара  Акция
0           1   True
1           2  False
2           3   True
3           4  False
4           5  False
5           6  False
6           7  False
7           1   True
8           3   True
```

---

> как работает `DataFrame.apply(func)`?

`DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0)` (axis=0 - значение по умолчанию) применяет функцию `func` к каждому **столбцу** DataFrame. Число вызовов `func` будет равным числу столбцов:

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   a  b  c
0  0  6  7
1  2  4  8
2  1  9  6
3  6  0  3
4  7  9  8


In [27]: df.apply(np.sum)
Out[27]:
a    16
b    28
c    32
dtype: int64

In [28]: df.apply(np.sum, axis=0)
Out[28]:
a    16
b    28
c    32
dtype: int64
```

`DataFrame.apply(func, axis=1)` применяет функцию `func` **построчно** - к каждой строке DataFrame:

```
In [29]: df.apply(np.sum, axis=1)
Out[29]:
0    13
1    14
2    16
3     9
4    24
dtype: int64
```

PS `DataFrame.apply(func, axis=1)` - часто работает даже медленнее обычного цикла, т.к. реализован в виде цикла, плюс накладные расходы на проверки...

Comment: возвращается ошибка 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0'. Как раз с этим и бьюсь. Либо все значения False либо ошибка

Comment: @DenisNovik, приведите небольшой пример данных, который помог бы воспроизвести ошибку...

Comment: относительно работы циклов в pandas можете проконсультировать? Если я пишу код как вы df['Код товара'].isin(list_promo) и затем применяю apply, то код и без цикла выполняется построчно, верно? В каких редких случаях тогда цикл приходиться использовать?

Comment: @DenisNovik, алгоритм действий такой: сначала пытаемся использовать векторизированные функции, если не получается пробуем `df.apply(..., axis=0)`, в самом крайнем случае, когда ничего не помогает используем циклы или `df.apply(..., axis=1)`. PS иногда при работе со _строковыми_ данными циклы работают быстрее, поэтому при работе со строками я обычно сравниваю разные методы, используя `%timeit ...` в iPython/Jupyter

Comment: а вектрозированные функции - это функции библиотеки numpy? Например, np.where, который вы мне уже как-то показывали? Он хорошо, но в моем понимании ограничен по количеству условий.

Comment: @DenisNovik, это функции Numpy/SciPy/Pandas/SciKit-Learn/etc., которые написаны на C/Cython и которые принимают на вход вектор или матрицу

Comment: спасибо большое за подробные и понятные объяснения. Вопрос удалось решить с вашей помощью!